# How to send Javascript array as Json combined with a html form?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am creating a restaurant menu app that a waiter can use to input orders.

I have a Js array called itemOrderList that I am storing item names in. I want to be able to send that list of item names as Json array with customer name form input field and item price to back end to be stored in my DB. I am having issues going about doing this. What should I do? Google dev tools says "ReferenceError: itemOrderList is not defined" where I am trying to stringify the Js array.

AngularJs code

```
 .controller('orderAddCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'dataService', function ($scope, $location, dataService) {

            $scope.itemOrderList = [];
            $scope.totalItemPrices = 0;

            $scope.addOrderToList = function (item) {
                console.log(item.itemName);
                $scope.addPricesToTotalItemPrices(item.itemPrice);
                $scope.itemOrderList.push(item.itemName);
            };

            $scope.addPricesToTotalItemPrices = function (price) {
                console.log(price);
                $scope.totalItemPrices += price ;
            };


            $scope.removeFromOrderToList = function (index) {
                console.log(index);
                $scope.itemOrderList.splice(index, 1);
            };

            $scope.createOrder = function (order) {
                var myJson = JSON.stringify(itemOrderList);
                order.orderPrice = totalItemPrices;
                order.orderItems = myJson;
                dataService.addOrder(order).then(function () {
                    $location.path('/');
                });
            };
```

Html

```
<form class="form-horizontal" ng-init="getItems()">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div>
                    <input ng-click="createOrder(order)" class="btn  btn-success" value="Create" />
                    <a href="#/" class="btn  btn-success">Back</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Customer Name</label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="order.customerName" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <h1>Total Price: ${{totalItemPrices}}</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="">
        <h2>Food Items</h2>
        <div class="row">
            <button class="btn btn-success col-3" ng-repeat="i in Items" ng-click="addOrderToList(i)">{{i.itemName}}</button>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="">
        <h2>Order Items</h2>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="i in itemOrderList track by $index">
                <p>{{i}}/<p>
                    <button ng-click="removeFromOrderToList($index)">Remove</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: it remains unclear what your actual problem is.

Comment: Sorry, it says ReferenceError: itemOrderList is not defined where I am trying to stringify the Js array. I'm not sure why it's not able to see the array?

Comment: Should not you be using $scope.itemOrderList in stringify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet you need to specify you're using vars declared in $scope as so...

```
$scope.createOrder = function (order) {
  var myJson = JSON.stringify($scope.itemOrderList);
  order.orderPrice = $scope.totalItemPrices;
  order.orderItems = myJson;
  dataService.addOrder(order).then(function () {
    $location.path('/');
  });
};
```